# Why does Blender force-quit?

Tags: shape-keys

If I slide the Shape Key value anywhere from 0, Blender will force-quit. What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: not slide the value....? ;)  you can...restart blender, try another blender version, restart your computer...

Comment: is your scene a really big scene?  Maybe it's just too much for your computer to handle